# Count the number of words in the linux dictionary file that start with a and end with z

Tags: linux

In a course task, I need to count the number of words that start with `a` and end with `z` using

```
grep | wc
```

and then print the number to a file in `/tmp`.

I think I don't know the syntax very well and would like some guidance.

Comment: is it a requirement to use both grep and wc because grep -c would probably be better

Comment: What is the question ? Do you expect us to solve this for you ? Then you will not learn anything (?!) Looks easy for the infamous chat'.

Comment: You may or may not be able to do something with this `\b[aA]\w+[zZ]\b`

Comment: You need to start looking at the man pages if you are having trouble understanding the syntax, `man grep`.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
grep -E '^a.*z$' /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l > /tmp/file.number
```